# Node.js Express and Parse.com

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parse-platform

I've set up a node.js server-app that I want to do some parse.com requests.
I basically want it to return the parse-object JSON-representation.

My route:

```js
var blog = require('./models/model');

app.get('/api/article/:permalink', function(req, res) {
  res.json(blog.getArticle(req.params.permalink));
});
```

And my model:

```js
var Parse = require('parse/node').Parse, // load the parse for node package
  keys = require('../../config/keys'); // keys config-file for hosted services

Parse.initialize(keys.app, keys.js);

module.exports = {

  getArticle: function(permalink) {
    "use strict";
    var Article = Parse.Object.extend('Article');
    var query = new Parse.Query(Article);
    query.include('category');
    query.include('profile');
    query.equalTo('permalink', permalink);
    query.find().then(function(results) {
      return results;
    }, function(error) {
      return error;
    });
  }

};
```

The thing is, this returns nothing when I call an article with a permalink that I know to exist (example: http://localhost/api/article/testFoo). I don't get any errors either.

My browser console flashes a message for a split second that reads:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://localhost/api/article/testFoo"
```

Any suggestions to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the return value of an async function. This can't work, you need to pass a callback (or the `res` object) to your `getArticle` function, which will then use it to send the data back.

With a callback:

```
app.get('/api/article/:permalink', function(req, res) {
  blog.getArticle(req.params.permalink, function(data) {res.json(data)});
});
```

...

```
getArticle: function(permalink,callback) {
```

...

```
    query.find().then(function(results) {
      callback(results);
    }, function(error) {
      callback({error: error});
    });
```

Comment: Fantastic! Nicely explained, thank you very much. (I'll accept as soon as I can)